# Struggling to install i386 packages on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 19.04, 32-bit

I have a 64-bit 19.04 installation, but if I attempt to install a 32-bit package (wine32 for example), I'm given this message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
```

with a list of i386 packages. If I attempt to install those, I'm often given an even longer list of i386 packages that I'm missing. I could go through and recursively keep attempting to install these i386 packages, but there must be some other way.

Most suggestions I've seen online are to run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, but this has had no effect. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is the contents of my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, if there's something I'm missing from here either:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner
```

Comment: Please do not add "SOLVED" to the question title. The right way to do it here is by "accepting" the most helpful answer which you already did.

Comment: @Aquova,  I think "https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO" link will solve your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have `disco` and `disco-security` in your sources list, so you are missing `disco-updates`, which may contain packages that are required as dependencies of other packages.

More generally, for a fully up-to-date system you need both `-updates` and `-security` in addition to the "base" repository.