# How to avoid removing essential packages and be able to run i386 programs? Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, 32-bit

I have a freshly installed XUbuntu 20.04.3 and I wanted to install support for running i386 programs by running:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

(as stated at [Installing 32-bit libraries on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522372/installing-32-bit-libraries-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-64-bit/524647#524647) )

The command 'install' tells me that it will remove tons of packages (alphabetically starting with accountsservice acl acpi-support acpid adduser adwaita-icon-theme alsa-base alsa-utils anacron apparmor apport) also with message "WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed." with packages like 'apt adduser' and so on.

My question is - why does this happen? What is going on? I did not have that problem on my previous Ubuntu's.

How to avoid removing essential packages and be able to run i386 programs?

Comment: Hi, sorry for incorrect version in the topic. It is LTS 20.04.3

Comment: This answer was posted for 19.04, I am not sure if it will fix your issue but it's definitely related.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161373/struggling-to-install-i386-packages-on-ubuntu-19-04?rq=1

Comment: Well it seems to be right! I had previously changed my 'Software&updates'  settings 'Updates' tab setting "For other packages, subscribe to = Security updates only"; after setting this to "All updates" the installation works without any trouble!
Thanks, I'm going to write this as an answer (or you can too).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 1):

T Br https://askubuntu.com/users/1383491/t-br had a great lead to the answer - [Struggling to install i386 packages on Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161373/struggling-to-install-i386-packages-on-ubuntu-19-04?rq=1)

I had previously changed my 'Software&updates' settings 'Updates' tab setting "For other packages, subscribe to = Security updates only"; after setting this to "All updates" the situation is fixed and installation works without any trouble!

Installer warning messages were confusing me, I did not think that the setting could lead to such situation.